# how to insert json received audio file in php mysql using blob?

Tags: php, blob

I am not able to get the audio from the json audio file, i have moved the file in local folder and not able to get the audio file from uploaded folder

here is my code where i am not able to get the file

```
//Getting the project upload path
    $file_path = 'H:\\uploader\\';
    //Attaching file name with the upload path
    $file_path = $file_path . basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path);
    $audio_content = file_get_contents($file_path);
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
    // Select Database
    mysql_select_db("csm", $con);
    // Specify the query to Insert Record
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl (blob) values ('$audio_content')";
    // execute query
    mysql_query($sql, $con);
    // Close The Connection
    mysql_close($con);
```

can anyone help me to solve it

Comment: try using like this `base64_encode(file_get_contents($file_path));`

Comment: its not recommended to store files in db just save the file path in db not the hole file..

Comment: i want to store the file in db and delete the local file after successful insertion. But i used base64_encode(file_get_contents($file_path)); but doesn't work

Comment: can you pls explain what error you get

Comment: i didn't got any error and it doesn't insert the file in db but it inserts the file name

Answer (score 0):

I have got the file content from temp path now you can save it in your db.

The issue is `basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'])`

```
    //Getting the project upload path
    $file_path = 'H:\\uploader\\';
    //Attaching file name with the upload path
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path);
    $audio_content = base64_encode(file_get_contents($file_path));
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
    // Select Database
    mysql_select_db("csm", $con);
    // Specify the query to Insert Record
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl (blob) values ('$audio_content')";
    // execute query
    mysql_query($sql, $con);
    // Close The Connection
    mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: still i didn't get the solution

Comment: are sure that he file exist in this location `$_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']` ??

Comment: what is getting inserted in db

Comment: file name is inserted